# Reversing sequence of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm learning C++ and recently got into this problem:

> reverse sequence of positive integers that are coming from std::cin, sequence ends when -1 is approached. This '-1' should not be a part of sequence. Print out reversed sequence, it also must end with -1.

So, I've written pretty straightforward code that does exactly that, it might be not the best in terms of performance, as if I counted right, overall O(N^2 / 2).

```
int n = 0;
vector<int> numbers; //placeholder vector for input

while (n != -1) { 
    cin >> n; 
    numbers.push_back(n);
}
numbers.erase(numbers.end() - 1); // -1 should not be the part of the vector, so I erase it
n = numbers.size() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i) { //swapping
    int tmp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[n - i];
    numbers[n - i] = tmp;
}
for (auto a : numbers) //printing out
    cout << a << " "; //each integer in input and output is separated by spacebar
cout << -1; //last element should be '-1'
```

Unfortunately, this code passes 4/10 test cases which was quite shocking for me.

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a hint of what is wrong with my code or any generic advices about performance.

Comment: By The Way: O(N^2/2) = O(N^2)

Comment: Try `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i, --n)` and replace `n - i` with `n`?

Comment: What test cases did you try running it on yourself?

Comment: @PaulHankin They are not mine, just automated test cases without any description. Anyway, I did a silly mistake that is now found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is when the length of the vector is even

for example if you have 4 elements your n = 4-1 = 3

your loop will go one step only  as n/2 = 3/2 = 1

so to fix this just change your loop to this `for (int i = 0; i <= n / 2; ++i)`

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is linear, there is no performance issues with it. It looks like you've got a problem with computing indexes while swapping array elements.

You would be better off not adding `-1` to the vector in the first place. Moreover, reversing should be done using [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). You also should pay attention to premature end of the input to ensure that your program does not hang if `-1` is never entered:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int n;
while (std::cin >> n) {
    if (n == -1) break;
    numbers.push_back(n);
}
std::reverse(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

Your output section looks good, although you should add `std::endl` or `'\n'` to the end of your output:

```
std::cout << -1 << std::endl;
```

You can also write the entire vector to `std::cout` using `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

**Edit:** It's for studying purpose, so I can't use std::reverse

Then you should rewrite your loop with iterators and `std::iter_swap`:

```
auto first = vector.begin();
auto last = vector.end();
while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
    std::iter_swap(first++, last);
}
```

In general, you want to avoid indexes in favor of iterators in order for your code to be idiomatic C++, and avoid potential off-by-one problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarks, very helpful. I actually did input loop just like you firstly, but I wasn't sure if it's good to check whether n is -1 n-times. So i came up with idea to just erase it after while without checking. It's for studying purpose, so I can't use std::reverse.

Comment: @Monstryyy Your code checks that n times too. It doesn't matter if the check is in the loop condition or not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed, you're absolutely right! I guess I'm just too stupid, somehow I did all the possible mistakes in such a simple task. And thanks for iterators, I'll definitely take a look at them.